# Unable to stream from Unity to XR Remote app on Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, 8thwall-xr

I am not able to make XR Remote stream data from Unity to the app. I downloaded 8thWallXR-Demo project for Unity and did all the necessary stuff in tutorial, but it still doesn't work. I also followed troubleshooting instructions (restarting the ADB), but nothing worked.

When I start the app, I can see both USB and the name of my PC (Wi-Fi connection). If I select USB, it shows "Waiting for USB" infinitely, and if I choose Wi-Fi connection, the title changes to "-529". I guess they are connected somehow, but they cannot establish streaming connection.

The weird thing about this is it works properly on my second computer at work. So I really don't know what could cause the trouble.

I use Windows. Both XR tools and phone app are updated.

Comment: Is the second computer at your work also Windows? What versions of Unity are you using in each setup? What version of Android is your device on? This can all help us debug what is going wrong.

Comment: Yes. Both computers use Windows 10 Home and Unity version 2019.1.9f1. My device uses Android 9.

Comment: Since both environments are the same, I'd recommend checking if your firewall is blocking the connection on the computer where this doesn't work:
https://www.8thwall.com/docs/xr/#known-issues--workarounds

Comment: I temporarily disabled firewall as well as antivirus software, however, none of it seems to be helping in resolving the issue.

Comment: Do you have any error logs that you can provide for the Android remote app? You can see the logs on the device by opening a terminal / shell and running the command `adb logcat`.

Comment: Hmm, I see now. When I start hte XR Remote app, it keeps constantly logging this error:
`UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper:ConvertFromJNIArray(IntPtr)
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject:_CallStatic(String, Object[])
XRInternal.XRRemoteClient:XRGetRemoteConnection()
MainSceneController:Update()
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 48)
AndroidJNIHelper.GetSignature: using Byte parameters is obsolete, use SByte parameters instead`

However, quick research didn't provide me with a way to solve this.

Comment: However, I found out  I get this exact same output at my second computer at work. So it looks like it doesn't matter really.

Comment: I may've found some clue. If I attach Visual Studio debugger to Unity and play in Editor with "Enable Remote" checked in XR Controller component, it throws out exception in XRInternalRemote.cs, in AcceptCallback() function. It throws exception at line `Socket tcpSocket = listener.EndAccept(ar)`. The exception (shortened):
`"System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: \'System.Net.Sockets.Socket\'.\r\n  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ThrowIfDisposedAndClosed () [0x0001b] in <...>:0 \r\n  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndAccept (System.Byte[]& buffer, ... "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. It is most probably a Unity bug. I opened Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools. In "Android" section, there are [five checkbox options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3rQo.png).

I unchecked the "Android NDK Installed with Unity (recommended)" checkbox. After that, I clicked Browse button, which automatically filled in [path to NDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt3Ra.png).

This made XR Remote stream work properly. However the weirdest part about this is it actually works even if I check that checkbox again.